# Get last element of list in Spark Dataframe column

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` that has the following schema.

```
root
 |-- memberId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- itemId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- weight: double (nullable = true)
```

Say, the DataFrame (called `df`) looks like this.

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|memberId   |items                                                                   |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|10000000001|[[1234567891, 104, 1.0], [1234567892, 103, 3.0]]                        |
|10000000002|[[1234567891, 103, 1.0], [1234567893, 102, 1.0], [1234567894, 101, 2.0]]|
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As can be seen, the `df` is a map of `memberId` to a `list` of `struct`s. I want to transform it such that I retrieve the last element in the list of `struct`s corresponding to each member. So, the resulting `DataFrame` should look like

```
+-----------+----------------------+
|memberId   |lastItem              |
+-----------+----------------------+
|10000000001|[1234567892, 103, 3.0]|
|10000000002|[1234567894, 101, 2.0]|
+-----------+----------------------+
```

I tried this

```
val newDf = df
  .withColumn("lastItem", last($"items"))
  .drop("items")
```

But this just throws an exception of the form:

```
grouping expressions sequence is empty, 
and '`memberId`' is not an aggregate function. 
Wrap '(last(`items`, false) AS `item`)' in 
windowing function(s) or wrap '`memberId`' in 
first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get
```

I believe this happens because `last` is an `aggregation` function and requires me to `.groupBy("memberId")` before I invoke `last`.

How can I do this? Use of `UDF`s is not encouraged when working with `DataFrame`s but I can't find a native function that can do what I intend to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `apply` method on `Column` of type array, with which you can access array elements:

```
val newDf = df
.withColumn("lastItem", $"items"(size($"items")-1))
.drop("items")
```

Edit:

to get the first n-1 items, I would use an UDF :

```
val sliceUDF = udf((arr:Seq[Row],from:Int,to:Int) => arr.slice(from,to).map{case Row(ts:Long,Id:Int,w:Double) => (ts,Id,w)})

val newDf = df
  .withColumn("subItems", sliceUDF($"items",lit(0),size($"items")-1))
  .drop("items")
```

Maybe it could also be done using pure DataFrame API, but I think it would be rather complicated (e.g. using a combination of `posexplode`, window-function and `collect_list`)